# не срабатывает плавное исчезновение блока jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

При удалении строк из таблицы, они не плавно исчезают, а резко, без анимаци

```
$('#users_del').click(function () {
    var row_id = [];
    $(".checked").each(function (indx, element) {
        row_id.push($(element).attr('id'));
    });
    $(".checked").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : '/admin/menu/users/users_del_db.php',
            data : {
                "row_id" : row_id
            },
            cache : false,
            beforeSend : function (html) {
                $("#reports").empty();
            },
            success : function (html) {
                $("#reports").fadeIn(500);
                $("#reports").append(html);
                $("#reports").delay(500);
                $("#reports").fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
});

<table>
 <tr id="<?=$data['users_id']?>" class="table_row checked">
           <td class="under_cell <?=$data['users_id']?>">
                <button id="<?=$data['users_id']?>" class="btn editor fa fa-info users_info" name="">
                </button>
                <td class="under_cell <?=$data['users_id']?>">
                     <?=$data['users_id']?></td>
                <td class="under_cell <?=$data['users_id']?>">
                     <?=$data['users_first_name']?></td>
                <td class="under_cell <?=$data['users_id']?>">
                     <?=$data['users_login']?></td>
                <td class="under_cell <?=$data['users_id']?>">
                     <?=$data['user_phone']?></td>
                <td class="under_cell <?=$data['users_id']?>">
                     <?=$data['users_email']?></td>
                <td class="under_cell <?=$data['users_id']?>">
                     <?=$data['users_last_activity']?></td>
                <td class="under_cell <?=$data['users_id']?>">
                     <?=$data['status']?></td>
      </tr>
</table>
<div id="reports"></div>
```

Comment: А  можно `html`, к которому это применяется? Какие-нибудь ошибки в консоли?  и что за символ `'` в начале и конце кода?

Comment: Символ добавил когда вставлял код в форму.

Comment: добавил тело таблицы

Comment: `$("#reports").empty();` - так не надо перед отправкой очищать и все

Comment: @Grundy  Тогда отчеты друг на друга накладываются в строке уведомлений. И это не решило проблему.

Comment: @Vasiliyp, я же не сказал - совсем не очищать, я сказал **не очищать перед отправкой**

Comment: @Grundy ага,  понял. Но это все-равно не решает проблемы.

Comment: @Vasiliyp, вполне решает, если перед очисткой скрыть элемент, потом очистить, потом показать

Comment: @Grundy не понял как это влияет на исчезновение строк таблицы (".checked")?  ("#reports") как раз отлично исчезает и появляется, но он никакого отношения к таблице не имеет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42293/discussion-between-grundy-and-vasiliy-p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как выяснилось в чате проблема заключается в установке прозрачности элементу `tr` в браузере `EDGE`/`IE` - в этом случае анимация не срабатывает.

В качестве обходного пути можно скрывать не строки, а ячейки:

```
$(".checked td").fadeOut(500, function () {
    $.ajax({...});
}
```

[Для IE11 даже баг такой есть](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4826575/)